# Check The Status Of Another Discord Bot

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

So i need a bot that tracks another bot's status. like if its online it will say in a channel (with an embed) "The Bot Is Online" And The Same if it goes offline and whenever someone does !status {botname} it shows the uptime/downtime of the bot and 'last online' date

if someone can make it happen i will really appricate it!

also i found this github rebo but it dosen't work, it just says the bot is online and whenever i type `!setup {channel}` it turns off
The Link to the Repo: https://github.com/sujalgoel/discord-bot-status-checker

Also uh it can be any language, i don't really want to add anything else .
Again, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you would need the privileged Presence intent, which you can enable in the Developer Portal.

[image: presence intent]

#### Tracking the bot's status

In order to have this work, we have to listen to the `presenceUpdate` event in discord.js. This event emits whenever someone's presence (a.k.a. status) updates.

Add this in your `index.js` file, or an event handler file:

```js
// put this with your other imports (and esm equivalent if necessary)
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

client.on("presenceUpdate", async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  // check if the member is the bot we're looking for, if not, return
  if (newPresence.member !== "your other bot id here") return;

  // check if the status (online, idle, dnd, offline) updated, if not, return
  if (oldPresence?.status === newPresence.status) return;

  // fetch the channel that we're sending a message in
  const channel = await client.channels.fetch("your updating channel id here");

  // create the embed
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${newPresence.member.displayName}'s status updated!`)
    .addField("Old status", oldPresence?.status ?? "offline")
    .addField("New status", newPresence.status ?? "offline");

  channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
});
```

Now, whenever we update the targeted bot's status (online, idle, dnd, offline), it should send the embed we created!

#### `!status` command

This one will be a bit harder. If you don't have or want to use a database, we will need to store it in a Collection. The important thing about a Collection is that it resets whenever your bot updates, meaning that even if your bot restarts, everything in that Collection is gone. Collections, rather than just a variable, allows you to store more than one bot's value if you need it in the future.

However, because I don't know what you want or what database you're using, we're going to use Collections.

In your `index.js` file from before:

```js
// put this with your other imports (and esm equivalent if necessary)
const { Collection, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

// create a collection to store our status data
const client.statusCollection = new Collection();
client.statusCollection.set("your other bot id here", Date.now());

client.on("presenceUpdate", async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  // check if the member is the bot we're looking for, if not, return
  if (newPresence.member !== "your other bot id here") return;

  // check if the status (online, idle, dnd, offline) updated, if not, return
  if (oldPresence?.status === newPresence.status) return;

  // fetch the channel that we're sending a message in
  const channel = await client.channels.fetch("your updating channel id here");

  // create the embed
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${newPresence.member.displayName}'s status updated!`)
    .addField("Old status", oldPresence?.status ?? "offline")
    .addField("New status", newPresence.status ?? "offline");

  channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

  // add the changes in our Collection if changed from/to offline
  if ((oldPresence?.status === "offline" || !oldPresence) || (newPresence.status === "offline")) {
    client.statusCollection.set("your other bot id here", Date.now());
  }
});
```

Assuming that you already have a prefix command handler (not slash commands) and that the `message`, `args` (array of arguments separated by spaces), and `client` exists, put this in a command file, and make sure it's in an async/await context:

```js
// put this at the top of the file
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

const bot = await message.guild.members.fetch("your other bot id here");
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`${bot.displayName}'s status`);

// if bot is currently offline
if ((bot.presence?.status === "offline") || (!bot.presence)) {
  const lastOnline = client.statusCollection.get("your other bot id here");
  embed.setDescription(`The bot is currently offline, it was last online at <t:${lastOnline / 1000}:F>`);
} else { // if bot is not currently offline
  const uptime = client.statusCollection.get("your other bot id here");
  embed.setDescription(`The bot is currently online, its uptime is ${uptime / 1000}`);
};

message.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
```

---

In no way is this the most perfect code, but, it does the trick and is a great starting point for you to add on. Some suggestions would be to add the tracker in an event handler rather than your `index.js` file, use a database rather than a local Collection, and of course, prettify the embed messages!