# Is it possible to check a Discord.js Bots status from outside that application?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am creating a status page for my "company". This status page is checking the status of the main site with a request, but I also want it to check if my Discord Bot is online. So essentially it would perform some request to check if the bot is online.

I did some searching, I found another post "[Check The Status Of Another Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516311/check-the-status-of-another-discord-bot)", but that is ran inside another Discord Bot. I want to run it on the status website with javascript if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either setup an exposed web server API directly within your Discord bot application that responds if the bot is online, or, for the sake of separation of concerns, create a third application that sits "between" your website and the bot that would be capable of both receiving `POST` requests from the Discord bot with its status updates and serve them over a `GET` endpoint to your website.

Comment: If you can, mark this answer as the accepted one for your question